# How to break the tight coupling between these React Presentational Components

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

Some tutorials/examples of React apps display data in what seems to have tightly coupled components. For example:

```
class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <div className="table-responsive">
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>A</th>
                      <th>B</th>
                      <th>C</th>
                      <th>D</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items.map(item => <ListItem key={item.id} ... />)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
```

You can imagine how `ListItem` looks like. There is no way `ListItem` can be used without `List` as they must share the same layout.

I don't see how that is helping create re-usable components. Is there a way around it?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What should be abstracted here in your opinion?

Comment: @Chris I think he's suggesting that `<ListItem />` isn't reusable because it can only be used within the context of a `<tbody>`.

Comment: @DanPrince exactly that

Comment: There are many ways to re-write this. Do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: No specific problem, it just feels wrong to write tightly coupled components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that the coupling is not actually that tight. You only need to make one change to use another component in your rendering loop and `<ListItem />` doesn't know anything about `<List />`.

I can't see any long term benefit, but you could make `<ListItem />` more general by allowing it to accept the contextual tags as props, or as arguments as a higher-order component.

```
function ListItem({ Row='tr', Cell='td', key, item }) {
  return (
    <Row key={key}>
      <Cell>{item}</Cell>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

This would allow you to use it in non-table contexts by passing different tags down.

```
<ListItem key={1} item="foo" Row="div" Cell="span" />
```

Which would render as more generic HTML.

```
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

You could do the same for `<List />` by having it accept the `<ListItem />` component as a prop too.

But I think it's more trouble than they're worth and you'd end up wasting a lot more time writing and testing these generic decoupled than you would if you just work around the fairly loose coupling in your example.

Comment: I guess it's not the end of the world. As no-one else is answering maybe it's not that big a deal.